# PyCharm: Unresolved reference with Scapy

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, scapy

I am working on a network tool that I write in python using scapy.
As IDE I am using Pycharm.
My Code works. So if I run it, everything works just as intended.

My problem is that PyCharm is giving me some errors.
It marks every use of `IP`, `TCP`, `Ether`, ... as `Undefined Reference to ...`

The relevant parts of my Code look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *

...  
...  

syn = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dst_ip) / TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dst_port, seq=src_seq, flags="S")

...
```

I tried many things I found using google, like adding my src folder as source root, I refreshed all caches I could find and restarted PyCharm dozens of times, but nothing worked...

Since the code works it's a minor problem, but still I'd like to have my IDE working as intended

I am working under MacOS and I use a Virtual Environment

Comment: Are you using Virtual environments?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention this...  Yes I am using a virtualenv

Comment: Are you configuring pycharm to use virtualenv?

Comment: yes, PyCharm has the VirtualEnv configured as "interpreter", and I installed all needed packets via PyCharm and not via pip inside the virtualenv

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solutions here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a PyCharm issue. Scapy uses [dynamic loading](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/all.py) (using `importlib`) to load many modules / custom modules, that pycharm does not detect. This allows the users to select which layers they want to have loaded.

The workaround is to import whatever you need from their related scapy file, without using `all`. It is cleaner but longer to do. Or you can use "add an exception" in your IDE, if you’re not looking for something clean.

Here are a few useful modules

- `scapy.layers.inet` where you can get IP, TCP..
- `scapy.layers.inet6`
- `scapy.layers.dns`
- `scapy.sendrecv` has srp, sr, sr1, sendp, send...
- `scapy.supersocket` to directly access scapy’s sockets
- `scapy.layers.l2` which has Ether, ARP..
- `scapy.layers.dot11` for 802.11 stuff
- `scapy.utils` for `wrpcap`, `rdpcap`...
- `scapy.config` for the `conf` object (which has properties such as `conf.route` or `conf.route6`)

What I advise to do is to open the Scapy shell (or import `from scapy.all import *` in a console) and check from which module a layer/function is by using `help(...)`. You can also check out the online API reference (it has a search bar) over [here](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.html)

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, try importing this way:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP, wrpcap, Ether
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Ether,IP... not defined directly in scapy.all  :-(

Now, PyCharm can give you the advice to import whatever you need from their related scapy file：
[image]