# PyCharm doesn't suggest autocompletion and marks unresolved reference

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I'm trying to make a simple scapy program but PyCharm doesn't suggest any code completion and marks an 'unresolved reference'. The program works, however.

I'm using the latest version of PyCharm on Mac OS 10.14 and my system python interpreter (`/usr/local/bin/python3.7`).

```py
from scapy.all import *

def arp_display(pkt):
    pkt.summary()
    if pkt[ARP].op == 1:
        print("%s demande qui est %s" % (pkt[ARP].psrc, pkt[ARP].pdst))
    elif pkt[ARP].opH == 2:
        print("%s possède l'addresse %s" % (pkt[ARP].psrc, pkt[ARP].hwsrc))

sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, count=10)
```

`ARP` is marked as unresolved reference and when I type `pkt.` and `ctrl` + `space` PyCharm doesn't suggest `show()`, `summary()`, and others methods like it should.

Comment: Edited question so it's intelligible. Basically, OP is using Pycharm on mac os with system interpreter. Pycharm doesn't suggest any autocompletion for elements of that particular module

Comment: Thank's for correction, not very good in english :S
What's OP ?

Comment: OP (original poster) is you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much against that :/

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402404/5459467 for a more complete answer)

Scapy [loads its layer modules dynamically](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/all.py). It allows Scapy users to toggle the loading of each layers separately, but the IDEs will fail to detect the imports.

What you can do to work around this is import the layers directly from their specific file, rather than `Scapy.all`.

For instance:

```
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff
```

Even though it takes more time, it's way cleaner (as you don't import everything). If you don't know in which module is a layer, just `help()` for it in Scapy's shell.