# Scapy: Undefined variable 'Dot11Beacon' and 'Dot11Elt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to do a simple wifi sniffer using scapy, on Ubuntu, but I encountered the following problems when I try to run the application:

```
Undefined variable 'Dot11Beacon' 
Undefined variable 'Dot11Elt'
```

For now I try to run the code in this following tutorial: https://www.shellvoide.com/python/how-to-code-a-simple-wireless-sniffer-in-python/

and it simple doesn't work because of the above errors. I am using Python 3 and the latest version of scapy, installed through pip.

Even if it's the same as in the tutorial, here are the parts of code I am using:

```
from scapy.all import *

sniff(iface=interface, prn=process_packet)

def process_packet(pak):
    if pak.haslayer(Dot11Beacon):
        if pak.getlayer(Dot11).addr2 not in F_bssids:
            F_bssids.append(pak.getlayer(Dot11).addr2)
            ssid = pak.getlayer(Dot11Elt).info
            if ssid == '' or pak.getlayer(Dot11Elt).ID != 0:
                print("Hidden Network Detected")
            print("Network Detected: %s" % (ssid))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved reference with scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691654/unresolved-reference-with-scapy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the same issue than
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402404/5459467
The same applies in PyCharm and Visual studio.
Have a look at my answer there.

> The workaround is to import whatever you need from their related scapy file, without using all. It is cleaner but longer to do. Or you can use "add an exception" in your IDE, if you’re not looking for something clean.

Comment: This solved the problem. If only I could had found the question before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If compiler says that variables are undefined then define them in your library without using `*`. There for use `from scapy.all import (Dot11,Dot11Beacon,Dot11Elt)` instead of `from scapy.all import *`

Comment: When I try to do this I receive the following errors:

No name 'Dot11' in module 'scapy.all'pylint(no-name-in-module)

No name 'Dot11Beacon' in module 'scapy.all'pylint(no-name-in-module)

No name 'Dot11Elt' in module 'scapy.all'pylint(no-name-in-module)

Comment: Now that I run the program everything works and python compiler itself doesn't crash. I think they were just py-lint errors and not actual compiler ones.

Comment: try to reinstall scapy. And also post your question in github also.