# Scapy, Pycharm issue needs solving [Cannot find reference 'ARP' in 'all.py']

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

Right... I've previously had this working correctly after about two days of slamming my head off my keyboard.... However, my SSD failed and I lost all my VM's and I dont remember what I did to solve this problem.

After doing some research, I've came to the conclusion that the issue is with Pycharm and how it does dynamic imports. Allthough, like I stated previously, ive had this working previously.

I've tried using recent and old versions of Pycharm and Python to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this? This seems to be a commonly asked question on Google with no clear solution.

[image: Screenshot]

```py
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP as ARP
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether as Ether
```

This is the solution I've found thus far. However, it would be helpful if this wasn't required and scapy.all could just be used as I have previously. If I ever find a solution to this myself I will post it here.

Comment: Hi, this sounds a lot like a duplicate of [Unresolved reference with scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691654/unresolved-reference-with-scapy) Could you check it out?

Comment: Ya, just go with individual imports; it's better practice anyways. `import *` should generally be avoided; regardless of what library you're using. With scapy, it pollutes the namespace with a massive number of irrelevant names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use VS Code and pipenv instead of Pycharm as you get all the benifits of Pycharm withouts it's issues.

1. Install pipenv globally using `sudo pip install pipenv`
2. Create a virtual enviroment using `pipenv install --python 3.8` for a specific version of python
3. Do `pipenv shell` to start the virtual enviroment
4. To install scapy use `pipenv install scapy`
5. Select the correct virtual enviroment using `Ctrl + Shift + P` when in VS Code to alter settings, search for "interpreter" and select the "Python: Select Interpreter" option and select your Pipenv enviroment
6. Run code using `python program.py` in the terminal

This way you can use `import scapy.all as scapy`, which isn't the best for production, but it is great for testing and rapid development.