# PyCharm Unresolved reference 'Ether' in scapy

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I am trying to make packet and I have red line under the "Ether" that says "Unresolved reference 'Ether'"
but the code works just fine. someone know how to I fix it?

```
from scapy.all import *

def dns_req(domain):
    mas = Ether()
    print(mas.show())
    return mas

def main():
    domain = input("Please enter the domain you want to search for: ")
    ip = dns_req(domain)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: Unresolved reference with Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691654/pycharm-unresolved-reference-with-scapy)

Comment: Essentially, use `from scapy.all import Ether` and specify the things you are importing as opposed to using `*`.